# C# Can't get the value from inside function like private/public void sumthin

Tags: datagridview

this is my code I'm stuck on this

```
    public void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

    {
                if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
                {
                   DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                   rfid = row.Cells["RFID"].Value.ToString();
                   string rfid2 = rfid;
                }
    }

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                MessageBox.Show(rfid2);  >> this is where i having the error he cant find rfid2 existance
    }
```

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `rfid2` is created and filled with a value in another method, your `button6_Click` can't see it.

If you want to access your variable from multiple methods inside class, make it a property of the class, like this.

```
private string rfid2;
```

Then you can access it from your methods by "this.rfid2", but only from within the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  //....
  string rfid2 = rfid;
}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(rfid2);
}
```

Hate to point out one of those "duh moments"...but are you not aware of the fact that rfid2 goes out of scope as soon as the dataGridView1_CellContentClick function completes?

Why would you think you could access rfid2 in button6_Click if rfid2 is clearly a local variable that's out of scope? Shouldn't the compiler be catching this bug for you?

Also why do you need rfid2 if you're not using it? The compiler should be telling you that rfid2 is unused and marking it with a squiggly line?